# More Powerful RFID card

Tags: upgrade

As of right now I know almost nothing about RFID's but I am willing to learn anything I need to. My goal is to be able to create a copy of my apartment RFID door key that is more powerful  so I do not have to press the RFID key/card against the sensor next to the door to open it, my goal is to walk up to the door and have it read the RFID key/card from my pocket.  Since the RFID reader is something outside of my control, I want to create a RFID key/card that is powerful enough to send its signal about 5ft from where it is.

Is something like this idea possible?

What stuff would I need to buy?
1. something to get the RFID info off my key
2. something to put the info I got from my original RFID onto the more powerful RFID
3. a more powerful RFID key for the key to register on the sensor which is about 2 feet from the front door, so a RFID card/key that can send a RFID signal 5ft

What is the best method for me to get the information out of  my RFID key and save it so I may put that information into a new more powerful RFID key/card

Comment: I think you need to do some research yourself first instead of asking us to do it for you (no offence). If you get stuck in a certain place, then ask for help.

Comment: Note that a more powerful key would send its signal to a wider audience, thereby creating a security hazard. Also, a passive RFID key is powered by the door's signal, so you need to check if the RFID is [passive or active](http://www.rfidlabeling.com/tag_types.html).

Comment: @Wozzie - While its possible to do what you want in theory, what likely will stop you, is the fact you don't know how the RFID system works in your apartment.  If you don't have that knowlege then you are unlikely going to have the technical expertise to figure it out nor the hardware to program the new RFID card.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of RFID tag. Most are passive, this means that the [detection range](http://www.skyrfid.com/RFID_Tag_Read_Ranges.php) for a specific type of tag is mostly dependent on the RFID reader.

If you know the details of your tag, it may in principle be possible to find a larger tag (with a bigger aerial) or a battery assisted tag that would be activated at a greater distance.

You would probably have to be able to register the new tag with the reader though. RFID tags for opening locks are likely to be carefully designed to resist duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn how the burger alarm in department store works.

that what can be done to make the idea you are attempting to work.

[image]